# With Java, how would I use the JasperServer Reports REST API to deploy an input control to the server?

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I have been unable to get Tibco support to come up with a solution for this, so I am thinking it is not possible, even though they document that it is.

**I want to:**

1. deploy an input control to the JasperReports server,
2. putting it into a specific folder,
3. using Java and their REST API,
4. and then list all the input controls back through a HTTP request
   (return a full list in json or xml)

**Requirements:**

**Language:** Java

**API:** JasperReports Server REST API

**Authentication:** POST

Then any HTTP method after the authentication via POST to send a JSON file to the server that defines and deploys the input control.

---

**artifacts:**

1. A single .java file  (using built in JDK libraries, or minimal dependencies declared in a pom.xml)
2. pom.xml

To understand this, I am hoping to find a bare bones solution that uses low level HTTP calls (no frameworks other than any HTTP client in Java).

I have searched, read the manual (it's horrible), many documents, so many things, and logged a support ticket with Tibco, and they are unable to find anyone in the company that can do this.